# How do I prove that the coordinate independant definitions of the Hodge dual operator are equivalent?

Tags: differential-geometry, hodge-theory

I am trying to show that the different ways of defining the Hodge star operator are equivalent.

I started with the following definition from the following lecture notes "An application of
discrete differential geometry to the spectral element method" by G. Oud.

> [image]

Then one can show that

> [image]

Where the index sets H and K are defined as $H:=\{1,...,p\}$ and $K:=\{p+1,...,n\}$. I am fine with that. Then it says that from that one can derive the formula:

> [image]

**My Questions:**

- Can equation 1.35 be shown by using linearity and the fact that $\star e^{H}=g(e^{K},e^{K})e^{K}$?
- How is the other direction shown, i.e, equation 1.35 implies equation 1.31? My guess is that I need to use $\star\star$, but then I only get the answer up to $(-1)^{k(n-k)}$.
- Is there a way to show equation 1.35 implies equation 1.31 without using $\star\star$?

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Comment: What do you mean by $e^H$ and $e^K$?

Comment: @Kajelad I added the definition of H and K